# How do you decode multiple and unknown charsets in Python?

Tags: python, character-encoding

I do a lot of text parsing, but always seem to run in to issues with decoding. Usually, I just look up the encoding via:

```
$ file -i filename.txt
filename.txt: text/x-diff; charset=utf-8
```

Then, specify it via my read line (shown here using [io](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html)).

`io.open(filename.txt, 'r', encoding='utf-8')`

However, whenever I come across new file encodings, I get:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x0a in position 0: truncated data'`

And I have to repeat the process of manually detecting and setting the new encoding. Is there a better way to parse multiple files with multiple and unknown charsets? I've tried a try/except block to successfully work with two encodings, but what about three or more? Is there an automatic detection method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this python package:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet

It will attempt to guess the encoding, you can then proceed for further processing of your input.

Comment: Not sure why, but chartdet is showing a file is ascii with 100% confidence when `file -i` shows utf-16le